# What is the output voltage of 1 Vp-p specified sin/cos encoders?

Tags: analog, sine, rotary-encoder

Encoders with sin/cos analog output (example model [Hengstler S21](https://www.hengstler.de/gfx/file/shop/encoder/S21/Datasheet_S21_en.pdf)) typically specify the output signal as 1 Vpp. This seems to be some kind of de-facto standard for the output amplitude.

If I understand correctly, normally Vpp means "Voltage Peak to Peak". So 1 Vpp would mean signal varying between -0.5 V and +0.5V. However the signals are usually differential, and +- 0.5V on each line would give 2 Vpp total differential signal.

The descriptions and images I can find online vary a lot.

For example this image from [OpenServoDrive](http://openservodrive.com/sincos-encoder-support/):

[image: Sin cos signal graph]

Compared with this image from [Wachendorff](https://www.wachendorff-automation.com/fileadmin/pim/WA/pdfs/en/General-technical-Data-and-safety-instructions-incremental-encoders-WDG-WDGI.pdf):

[image: Different sin-cos signal graph]

And then some pages like [Motion Control Tips](https://www.motioncontroltips.com/what-is-a-sine-encoder-aka-sine-cosine-encoder/) suggest that each of the differential signals is 0.5 Vp-p, yielding the total 1 Vp-p. But I guess that varies between manufacturers, as for some the other differential signal is said to be constant reference voltage.

I do realize that the amplitude is not critical for accuracy, as the atan2() of the two signals remains the same. However it is important information for designing the analog input range.

**Is my interpretation correct that the differential voltage between SIN+ and SIN- varies between -0.5 V and +0.5 V?**

Comment: "I do realize that the amplitude is not critical for accuracy, as the atan2() of the two signals remains the same." As long as the two channels have the _same_ amplitude, that amplitude is not critical. However, the equality of amplitudes **is** critical for accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

The picture from [OpenServoDrive](http://openservodrive.com/sincos-encoder-support/) is wrong. If a single ended signal goes from +1V to -1V, then it's peak-to-peak value is 2V and the amplitude is 1V.

In case of the [Henglstler S21](https://www.hengstler.de/gfx/file/shop/encoder/S21/Datasheet_S21_en.pdf), the datasheet states that it is a 1Vpp differential signal with offset 2.5V. This means that the voltage between A+ and Common goes from 3V to 2V (1Vpp single ended) while the voltage between A- and Common goes from 2V to 3V (1Vpp single ended).

The (differential) voltage between A+ and A- nodes goes from +1V to -1V which is 2Vpp.

[image]

Comment: Somehow I'm still confused by your answer, "goes from 3V to 2V (0.5Vpp single ended)" seems like that would be 1 Vpp?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I fixed my answer.